# Passing variable in insomnia graphql request

Tags: graphql, insomnia

in the graphql request i need to use environment variables, but i didn't find correct way to do this. in my request i have to provide id to get information about certain county.
i've tried to address them as _.var_name and no result. I've tried to call them like $var_name but it says that this variable is not defined. So question is how to address environment variable in query, or how to define $ss variable from my example on the picture ?
Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Query

```
query affiliations($last: Int) {
   affiliations(last: $last) {
    totalCount
  }
}
```

Query variables

```
{
  "last": "{{ _.envvar_name }}"
}
```